# Understanding how bootstrap works in a Ruby on Rails (4) application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have an existing Ruby on Rails 4 application and I have set up bootstrap within. The buttons, forms and other small things I've utilised have been great!

Now I am absolutely perplexed when it comes to bootstrap and responsive design. From what I've read, embedding bootstrap into your app should be responsive out of the box, but this doesn't seem to be the case (or maybe I'm doing it wrong).

In my application.html.erb head tag I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I've looked at [this section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) on the bootstrap site, but I don't see how adding hidden/visible classes is going to help my case, especially when header/footer widths need to change when the browser gets smaller.

I've been doing stuff like this so far:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 175px) and (max-width : 400px)  {
  /* styles here for 175px to 400px */
}
```

So what I've been doing is setting up my own media queries. **Now my question is: IS setting up media queries necessary when using the bootstrap framework?** I've had some OK success so far using my own queries, but it's very, very tedious: everything on my site looks pretty good when the browser is large, but when it gets small, everything goes to shit.

If anyone could offer some insight on this, it would be much appreciated. I feel like I'm making responsive design much harder than it ought to be.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate bootstrap into your app does not mean your website become responsive. It depends on the elements and classes that you are using on your site. If you have lots of custom CSS classes then you will need to define your own @media query.

In this case, I think you should take a deeper look into your app to see if you are really using Bootstrap classes in all places. If you see strange behaviors on mobile devices, then it  should be because of your custom CSS classes

Comment: Yeah I definitely have a ton of custom css going on and my application looks absolutely horrid on mobile, like not even usable its that bad.

Comment: @DnfD if you want to use bootstrap effectively and efficiently then i think you should try to replace your classes with bootstrap classes. Go slow one page at a time, it might look like a lot of work but it isn't as bootstrap has a wide range of classes which i'm sure would be enough. You manly need to give those grid classes to make width of your divs fluid and if you like it and think it's not much of work then you can move on to other pages

Answer (score 1):

If you look into [bootstraps documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), bootstrap 3 has a lot of css features which will help you to make your app responsive.

[`Grid System:`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Bootstrap 3 provides you grid classes according to your device like: `col-md-1`(for medium size desktop), `col-sm-1`(for your tablet) ,`col-xs-1`(for your mobile) so if you want to resize a particular element according to your device you can give that element classes like:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-xs-2"></div>
```

Now this div will have different width depending on the device width.

[`Media Queries:`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Bootstrap 3 use the following media queries in our Less files to create the key breakpoints in grid system.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

*Media queries will be helpful if you want to change typography or want to override any style according to device*

[`Images:`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)

Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

[`Responsive Utilities`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

For faster mobile-friendly development, use these utility classes like `.visible-xs, .visible-sm etc` for showing and hiding content by device. You can simply apply these classes to any element and they will be visible or hidden according to your device